# Implement interface inside PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, interface, android-pageradapter

I tried to implement an interface in a PagerAdapter that is held by a Recycler inside a Fragment. I have a simple class that need to call a method from PagerAdapter something like this .

```
public class Manager{

  public void play(Uri uri) {
    PagerAdapter.setUri(uri);
   }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `tried to implement an interaface` - create interface instead of class & implement interface in adapter class. Change `public class Manager` to `public interface Manager{}`

Comment: its not working.